# How to round decimal place of a single column in a csv array using php?

Tags: php, html, arrays, csv, decimal

I have some php code to get a csv file, put it into an array, and display the array in an html table.  This code will be used for a data file with several (about 10) columns.  I want to round the data points to 2 decimal places, and have been able to do so using $val = round($val, 2).  However, when used within my code, it also changes the format of the time column so instead of 12:00 it displays 12.  If anyone knows how to change the decimal format for certain columns in the array while leaving the time column alone, please let me know.  Here is the code I have now:

```
$out = '';
echo "<th> Time </th><th> Temperature </th><th> Speed  </th>";
$handle = fopen("fakedata.csv", "r");

$columns = array(1,3,5);
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $out = ("<tr>\r\n").$out;
        foreach ($data as $index=>$val) {
                if (in_array($index+1, $columns))
            {
                    $val = round($val, 2);
                    $out = ("\t<td>$val</td>\r\n").$out;
            }
    }

        echo("</tr>\r\n");
} //end while
echo $out;

echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```

(I know the $out stuff is weird, but its to flip the row order and display the most recent data first).  Anyways, my main problem is changing the decimal format for certain rows of the csv array, in this case change only the $column[3] or third column to 2 decimal places.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another if to check if it is on the third column, this case I used the shorthand [Ternary](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) operator.

```
if (in_array($index+1, $columns)) {
    $val = ($index+1 == 3) ? round($val, 2) : $val;
    $out = ("\t<td>$val</td>\r\n").$out;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! I have one more question.  With this array setup, is there any way I can change the code so that only a certain number of rows are displayed in the html table?  The data file I will be working with keeps updating with many rows, so I only want to display about 50 or 100.  Thanks again.

Comment: In your foreach loop keep a counter. At the end of the loop increase it, and at the top use an if to check if counter < 50. Or you could just use if($index <=50)

Comment: I am having a problem figuring out exactly where to place the counter (sorry I'm new to PHP).  Here is what I have to test it but the table does not change:

`$counter = 0;`


 `foreach ($data as $index=>$val) {`
       `if ((in_array($index+1, $columns)) and ($counter <=2))`
       `{`
 `$val = ($index+1 == 3) ? round($val, 2) : $val;`
 `$out = ("\t<td>$val</td>\r\n").$out;`
 `$counter++;`
       ` }`
    `}`

For this test I want it to only show 2 rows, but it still shows them all. Sorry that the code is hard to read in this comment.

Comment: if ((in_array($index+1, $columns) && ($counter <=2)) {

Comment: You can't use 'and' like that instead use &&

Answer (score 0):

What about relying on the magic of sprintf()?
Instead of:

```
$val = round($val, 2);
$out = ("\t<td>$val</td>\r\n").$out;
```

try:

```
$out = sprintf("\t<td>% 6.2f</td>\r\n%s",$val,$out);
```